# Error while using Apache Derby Embedded Database

Tags: java, derby

I am getting the following error while executing my java application:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:flightdb;create=true
   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
   at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
   at airline_reservation_system.Derby.<init>(Derby.java:19)
```

The error is occurring in this code from Derby.java

```
public Derby() throws SQLException {
    databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:flightdb;create=true";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL);
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    createTables();
}
```

What could be the reason for this? Do I have to start anything for Derby to work? As I am using an embedded database, I guess that should not be an issue.

I have included the following in pom.xml too:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.15.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As I am using Maven and embedded Derby, I assume I shouldn't have to do any extra setup or install any jar file separately. I'm not sure why I am still getting this error.

Here is an MRE:

```
package mwe;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Derby {
    private String databaseURL;
    private Connection conn;
    private Statement statement;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        new Derby();
    }

    public Derby() throws SQLException {
        databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:flightdb;create=true";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>code</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.9</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${maven.compiler.source}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derbyclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree

```
mvn dependency:tree
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for groupId:code:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin @ line 44, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------------< groupId:code >----------------------------
[INFO] Building code 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ code ---
[INFO] groupId:code:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derbyclient:jar:10.15.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.derby:derbyshared:jar:10.15.2.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.15.2.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.003 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-07T17:14:20+05:30
```

Comment: Derby is included only for unit tests (`<scope>test</scope>`). Is your error happening while running unit tests ?

Comment: I removed that scope but still the same error. It's happening while running the actual program. I don't have any unit tests

Comment: When you say embedded, are you talking about some IDE to which derby is embedded? I'm asking this as NetBeans IDE has derby database embedded so wanted a bit of clarity!

Comment: Nopes. No IDE involved. By embedded I mean the normal Embedded Apache Derby Database which can be used programmatically and the database is stored as a file. There is not need to start a server. I am using Intellij which doesn't have embedded inbuilt

Comment: I have updated with minimal reproducible example

Comment: You can check the `mvn dependency:tree` to ensure default scope for the driver is either compile or runtime. Also, how do you launch your program (command line, ide, other mean) ? It's important, to know how the classpath is resolved when the jvm launches.

Comment: I think you might need `derbyclient` as a dependency

Comment: @amanin I have updated the OP with the output of `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @g00se derbyclient is already there in the pom.xml

Comment: For Derby embedded, you need to add the `org.apache.derby:derbytools` dependency, see the duplicate.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried adding that dependency in pom.xml I still get the same error. Could you run it on your computer? (I have posted the MRE in OP)

Comment: fwiw, of all the databases I've worked with, Derby has been the most problematic in getting a connection

Comment: It works fine for me (curiously, even without adding derbytools) when using `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="mwe.Derby"`. How are you running your application? It sounds like you don't include the library on the runtime classpath.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am just right-clicking on Derby file -> Run inside Intellij
I even tried with `java mwe.Derby` But same error.

Comment: `java mwe.Derby` obviously will not work, because you don't have the necessary libraries on the classpath (you would need to explicitly specify them using the `-cp` option). Options like "Run inside IntelliJ" only work if you have either imported the entire Maven project in IntelliJ (that is, Maven defines the classpath in your IntelliJ project), or if you have manually setup the classpath inside IntelliJ, otherwise, once again, you don't have the necessary libraries on the classpath.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried with this command `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="mwe.Derby"` and it worked finally. Looks like if I have to run a program from the command line this is an ideal approach. I am still not sure how to get Intellij to run it. What configurations would be missing.

Comment: You need to import the Maven pom.xml as a new project.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks that worked. That's a little weird. So if I just open a maven project without selecting pom.xml then maven doesn't define the classpath when I execute it.

Comment: On initial import of the project in IntelliJ, you need to select the pom.xml, on subsequent use you can just select the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Might help you

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); // (for network)
```

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"); // (for embedded - afaicr)
```

Personally I've had problems loading the driver with higher versions. I'd be happy to be instructed ;) I suspect the manner of driver loading has changed
UPDATE: The latest is JDBC 4.0-enabled and is autoloaded. It loads ok with `DriverManager.getConnection`